# class method signature with *const* or without *const*?

Tags: c++, constants

I get the following error in Eclipse when trying to compile (c++)

> ../CardDeck.cpp:17:22: error: passing ‘const CardDeck’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int CardDeck::size()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

if I change **int size()** method to **int size() const** the error msg is gone and its compiled. I dont know why ?

the **.H** file is the following :

```
  #include "Card.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class CardDeck{
    private:
        vector<Card*> deck;

    public:

        int size();
        CardDeck();
        CardDeck(const CardDeck& rhs);
        CardDeck& operator=(const CardDeck& rhs);
        Card& draw();
        Card& top();

        bool isEmpty();
        void clear();
        int value();
        CardDeck& operator+=(const CardDeck& rhs); /// not sure if to return ref
        CardDeck& operator+(const CardDeck& rhs);
        friend CardDeck&  operator*(unsigned int num,CardDeck& rhs);
        friend CardDeck&  operator*(CardDeck& lhs,unsigned int num);
        bool operator<=(const CardDeck& rhs );
        bool operator>=(const CardDeck& rhs);
        bool operator<(const CardDeck& rhs);
        bool operator>(const CardDeck& rhs);
        bool operator==(const CardDeck& rhs);
        bool operator!=(const CardDeck& rhs);
        Card*  operator[](int i);
};
```

and the **C++** file is :

```
#include "CardDeck.h"
int CardDeck::size() {
    return this->deck.size();
}
CardDeck::CardDeck(){};
CardDeck::CardDeck(const CardDeck& rhs){
    this->clear();
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<rhs.size();i++){
        Card* current_card = rhs.deck[i];
        Card* new_copy = new Card(*current_card);
        this->deck.push_back(new_copy);
    }


}
Card* CardDeck::operator[](int i) {
    return this->deck[i];
}



void CardDeck::clear(){
    vector<Card*>::iterator it ;
    for(it=this->deck.begin();it != this->deck.end();++it){
        Card* temp = *it;
        this->deck.erase(it);
        delete(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: change `for (i=0;i<rhs.size();i++){` to `for (i=0;i<rhs.deck.size();i++){` and the error should go away

Comment: @jcxz: This only shadows the real problem.

Comment: By the way... your `clear` function is needlessly complicated. Just do all the `delete`s first and then call `deck.clear();`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I don't agree. This is just another way to write it. It does not shadow anything. `rhs` is still const, one cannot change it. Although providing an explanation for the error would probably be more beneficial to OP, but that is done in the answer already.

Comment: @jcxz: It shadows the design error of `size()` being non-`const` by preventing the helpful compilation error message.

Comment: @ChristianHackl well, if you put it that way, then yes, I agree. However in case OP did not want to provide a const overload (for some reason), then this is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your copy constructor `CardDeck::CardDeck(const CardDeck& rhs)`, `rhs` is a reference to a `const` `CardDeck` object.

So `rhs.size()` will not compile unless `size()` is explicitly marked as being `const`. That's what your compiler is telling you.

It's good practice to have your code as `const`-correct as possible as this prevents errant changes to the member data in a class. Really, `isEmpty()`, and possibly `value()` should be marked `const` too, as should all the overloaded relational operators.

Comment: ... and all the bool operators.

Comment: with const object you can run only const methods ?

Comment: Absolutely. You wouldn't want `rhs` to be changed would you?

Comment: got it, thnx a lot for your help