# `int size() const` or `const int size()`

Tags: c++, vector, constants

I am working on an implementation of a simple `Vector` class that forms a container for a constant sized double array (following the example on page 51 of [A Tour of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour.html)). My issue is with the method `int size() const`. It feels odd to define it this way, instead of `const int size()`. Both seem to work. Does anyone know the difference, if there is any?

Below is the class declaration and the definition of `Vector::size()`.

```
class Vector{

public:
    Vector(int);
    Vector(std::initializer_list<double>);
    ~Vector(){delete[] elem;}
    double& operator[](int);
    int size() const;

private:
    int sz;
    double* elem;
};

int Vector::size() const{
    return sz;
}
```

**Note:** I found similar posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723575/class-method-signature-with-const-or-without-const),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)), but they do not answer my question.

Comment: In `const int size()` `const` is useless, you return a const temporary integer. `int size() const` says it's a `size` method which does not modifies class when called, so you can call it for const `Vector` object.

Comment: const at the end means the function cannot change object members

Comment: The two are entirely different. `const int size()` means that what you return shall be treated as `const` which makes little sense for a type like integer which will be returned by value. `int size() const` tells the compiler that you do not intend to modify any member of your vector. You can add a dummy member to your vector and try to assign to it in your size method using either declaration. You will see the difference.

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff "I think it means that you can't modify the method by inheritance" - It means no such thing. It means the function returns a `const int`, nothing else.

Comment: I learned a lot from these comments. I wish this was explained in the book too!

Answer (score 3):

Please mind that:
 1. `const int foo();` means: foo returns const integer value
 2. `int foo() const` means: foo returns integer value, and doesn't modify anything.

This somehow conform with reading from right - it's please see that @2 is const function. Whereas linter in @1 will tell you that const on return value will be ignored.